# React Js Redux with .net core 2.1 Framework error

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, redux

Started new learning on React Js Redux. But facing below error.
Followed below video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXO97nDl5IA&t=915s

```
The above error occurred in the <Dialog> component:
    in Dialog (at DeptList.js:100)
    in div (at DeptList.js:87)
    in DeptList (created by Connect(DeptList))
    in Connect(DeptList) (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:14)
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col (at Layout.js:14)
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (at Layout.js:10)
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (at Layout.js:9)
    in Unknown (at App.js:10)
    in Unknown (at src/index.js:26)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (at src/index.js:25)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:24)
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
. index.js:2177
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
If i comment below code, it is working

```
  <Dialog visible={this.state.displayDialog} style={{ 'width': '380px' }}
                header="Dept Details" modal={true}
                footer={dialogFooter}
                onHide={() => this.setState({ displayDialog: false })}>
                {
                    this.state.dept &&
                    <div className="p-grid p-fluid">
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="DName">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <InputText id="DName" onChange={(e) => { this.updateProperty('DName', e.target.value) }}
                                value={this.state.dept.DName} />



                        </div>
                        <div style={{ paddingTop: '10px' }}>
                            <label htmlFor="Location">Location</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <InputText id="Location" onChange={(e) => { this.updateProperty('Location', e.target.value) }}
                                value={this.state.dept.Location} />



                        </div>

                    </div>


                }
            </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, one of the components you are using there as `<Component>` (JSX) is actually `undefined`. It also proceeds to tell you the line number, but you didn't add that so I have no idea where that happens.
Like the error says, identify the component that is `undefined` by the line numbers given and check if you imported it correctly and exported it correctly from the other file. If you need help with that, add your imports and exports to this question.

Generally, the tutorial you are watching there is using a quite old styles of React, Redux as well as react-redux.
Nowadays you would only be using `connect` for class components and in modern React code you would almost never write any class components.
Also, you should not be writing "plain redux" by hand, but use the official Redux Toolkit.

I can't tell you about a more modern React tutorial, but for Redux, you probably want to follow the [official "Redux Essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Also, there is not really anything specific to "using React/Redux with any server-side-framework" (unless there would be specific bindings, which does not seem to be the case here), apart from maybe the initial setup. So you are not limited to ".net core tutorials".

Comment: Thanks for inputs .I have idenitified the error . If i comment <Dialog> my page is loading but if i include it . it throws an error. It might have been related to version issue of prime react.